# Can you add multiple git repositories to a team project in tfs / tfs service?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I'm currently using tfs service for a project which involves several different parts (i.e. a website, a phone app etc). Some of these parts really belong in their own repositories, especially as some are .net and some are java / android.

Is there any way to add multiple git repositories to a team project in tfs / tfs service?

I could create independent team projects, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create multiple git repositories under a single Team Project.  Navigate to the Code Explorer, and locate the repository chooser in the web interface and select *Manage Repositories...*

[image: Repository Chooser]

From the repository manager, you can add a new repository:

[image]

This, of course, is provided that the Team Project uses Git as the version control provider - you can't mix and match Git repositories and Team Foundation Version Control in a single Team Project.

Comment: You can do this but be aware it breaks integration with Work item tracking if the repo has a different name to the project. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 and you can only associate/link a commit with a TFS work item if the repo has the same name as the project.

Comment: As @nrjohnstone mentioned, this appears to be a major current limitation. I asked a followup question about "How do we connect to TFS from all Git repositories in a Team Project?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616639/how-do-we-connect-to-tfs-from-all-git-repositories-in-a-team-project

Comment: The link in the comment above by @CameronTaggart shows how to get all of the TFS integration working with multiple repos :)

Comment: Obviously this question is pretty old, but I'll just point out that you can now mix TFVC and Git repositories in the same team project.