# How do we connect to TFS from all Git repositories in a Team Project?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm running the latest Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate at work with Update 1. We have the latest Team Foundation Server 2013 as well. Several of us are very excited about the new Git repository integration, but there appears to be a pretty big limitation. We want to add multiple Git repositories to a single Team Project and be able to access the Builds and the Work Items from Visual Studio 2013. It currently only works if your Git repository is named the same as the Team Project.

This is also a limitation for Visual Studio Online as well. My open source SourceLink project only shows Work Items and Builds in Visual Studio 2013 because I've named the remote VSO repository `origin` and the Team Project and Git Repository are both named SourceLink.

Visual Studio 2013 [Update 2 CTP 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432) looks like it has some nice Git updates, however, I don't see anything about this. Are there any plans to address this? We want to be able to access Work Items and Builds from every Git repository in a Team Project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 should work with multiple repositories per team project. How did you clone your Git repositories? Have you navigated to the Connect Team Explorer page? If you navigate to the Connect Team Explorer page (the "plug" icon in the Team Explorer toolbar), is your Team Project listed? If you navigate to the Connect page, connect to the team project, and then refresh that page (using the refresh icon in the Team Explorer tool bar), do the extra repositories show up?

Comment: Thank you @jamill! It does work. I'll document below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@jamill clued me into the solution in the comments above. Git has a slightly different workflow than what we are used to with TFVC. You must connect to the repository, not just the Team Project. I had to click the refresh button for the for repositories to show up, and then double click on the repository name to connect. After that, Work Items and Build show up as expected. Yay!

Before

[image]

Connect to the Git Repository in the Team Project

[image]

Tada!

[image]

Comment: Looks like this only works with VS 2013. If you are using VS 2012 with the Visual Studio Tools For Git Extension, the multiple repos don't show up in the Team Explorer - Connect page.

Comment: cannot reprodue with VS2015