# Git command to show all the Git repositories under one VSO TFS project

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

In TFS Git, e.g. Visual Studio Online, one can have multiple Git repositories under a single TFS project; [Willy-P Shaub's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2014/11/19/many-git-repositories-but-one-team-project-to-rule-them-all.aspx) and [Edward Thomson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595667/575530) give the details.

What is the TFS Git command (i.e. at the terminal or command line) to list all the repositories present under a TFS project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit : Microsoft released a new command line to manage VSTS and there is now something to do that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/vsts/code/repo?view=vsts-cli-latest#vsts_code_repo_list

---

Previous answer:

Due to the fact how git works (you are inside a local repository and it only knows its remotes), there is no git command that will do that.

Perhaps you should have a look at [the TFS rest api](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/repositories) and query that with `curl`:

```
curl -u {username} https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/[{project}]/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0
```

Or even better write your own little command using the TFS api (a wrapper around the rest api).

Perhaps Microsoft has improved the tf.exe command line to get what you are looking for but I didn't have a look since tfs support git...

Comment: There do seem to be git commands that work outside a local repository. The obvious one is `git init` but I also find this one very useful `git ls-remote https://mycrazyteam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyCrazyProject` which works fine outside a local repository. I'm hoping that TFS Git has an extension that will list Git remotes for a TFS project. I like the curl idea - thanks