# Unable to create multiple repos per team project in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, tfs-2015, team-project

- I have installed Team Foundation Server Update 1 on one of my
  servers.
- I have created a new team project using git as the source
  control type. I am trying to add another repo to the same project. I
  have read up on how I should be able to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591461/can-you-add-multiple-git-repositories-to-a-team-project-in-tfs-tfs-service).
- When I attempt to follow the steps, no new repo is created, no error is
  generated, and the pop-up window just retains its state on the screen
  with no indication of success or failure (Screenshot below - UI is
  still responsive, and I can cancel, but clicking "Create" any number
  of times produces no result).
- I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this since there is no exception message, so any help is appreciated.

[image: Create New repo doesn't work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I would raise a support request with MSFT on: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/support-overview-vs

Things to try:

1. Have you tried closing your browser, clearing your cache?
2. Log out, clear your cache and close your browser?
3. Different browser?

All should be unnecessary... But you never know

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot. I have tried all of the above already, as well as had another admin attempt this with the same results.